# Implementing iterator interface with map doesn't work with java 8 streams

Tags: groovy, coercion

I'll start with the code:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport
def hasMore1 = true
def iter1 = new Iterator<Integer>() {
    boolean hasNext() { def retVal = hasMore1; hasMore1 = false; retVal }
    Integer next() { 42 }
}

def hasMore2 = true
def iter2 = [
    hasNext: { -> def retVal = hasMore2; hasMore2 = false; retVal },
    next: { -> 42 }
] as Iterator<Integer>

def stream1 = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliterator(iter1, 1, 0), false)
def stream2 = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliterator(iter2, 1, 0), false)        
stream1.forEach { println it } // prints 42
stream2.forEach { println it } // throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

These two methods of implementing an iterator in groovy seem to be semantically equivalent, and in normal use cases, like iterating with foreach, and use in list comprehensions all seem to treat them the same.  The Java 8 Streams api however seems to treat them different as demonstrated above.  How and why?  Is there anything I can do to the map-implementing interface version to make it behave correctly?

Comment: What version of groovy?

Comment: Interestingly it complains about lacking a `forEachRemaining` method, which is a [default method on Iterator interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: groovy version 2.3.6.  jdk 1.8.0_11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this has been fixed in groovy 2.3.8

It may have been similar to this bug that was fixed in the same release:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7104